# WSL hosts file with custom domain

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, hosts

I create a basic express app

```js
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.get("*", (req, res) => {;
  res.contentType('html');
  res.send("HELLO FROM WSL");
});
const port = 80
app.listen(port);
```

Then I add following entrie in `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`

```
127.0.0.1        custom.local
```

Then I shutdown wsl `wsl --shutdown` and re-open to start my express app.

If I check hosts file from WSL (`cat /etc/hosts`), I got following result

```
# This file was automatically generated by WSL. To stop automatic generation of this file, add the following entry to /etc/wsl.conf:
# [network]
# generateHosts = false
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       LAPTOP-ZECKA.localdomain        LAPTOP-ZECKA
127.0.0.1       custom.local
```

Then I go to `http://custom.local` trough chome in windows. But it's doesn't display my express app. (If i run express on windows instead of wsl it's work well).

What's wrong on my hosts file ?

Comment: I did have the same issue. I ran ``ifconfig`` in WSL and copied the IP and added this to my host file. This works but now I need to reconfigure this on every reboot as the IP keeps changing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally I found a solution on github: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5728#issuecomment-917295590

Instead declare domain like that

```
127.0.0.1        custom.local
```

I do as follow:

```
127.0.0.1   custom.local
::1         custom.local localhost
```

Answer (score -1):

Previously, I had my WSL in version 1 and everything worked fine. Then I decided to upgrade to WSL 2 and - similar to many others - I lost internet connection. Thankfully, I could easily bring it back by running:

sudo bash -c 'echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > /etc/resolv.conf'

Apparently, it was just a DNS issue. I could live with that. However, then I restarted my WSL and the nameserver was set back to 172.31.208.1. So I decided to do exactly what was written in the comments in /etc/resolv.conf:

## This file was automatically generated by WSL. To stop automatic generation of this file, add the following entry to /etc/wsl.conf:

## [network]

## generateResolvConf = false

And ran the following lines:

sudo bash -c 'echo "[network]" > /etc/wsl.conf'
sudo bash -c 'echo "generateResolvConf = false" >> /etc/wsl.conf'
I was proud that I resolved the issue so elegantly until I restarted my WSL again. Now, resolv.conf was in red and not accessible from Ubuntu. When I tried to access it from Windows, I saw just an empty file.

Expected behavior
After restarting WSL, resolv.conf keeps the user-defined values.

Actual behavior
After restarting WSL, resolv.conf is empty or not accessible at all.